# Eclipse & Tomcat Error: HTTP Status 404 – Not Found:

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat8

**Description**: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

**This is my HomeController Class:**

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showPage() {
        return "main-menu";
    }
}
```

**This is my Web.xml File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

    <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**This is spring-mvc-demo-servlet file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.springdemo" />

    <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**This is main-menu.jsp file**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<body>

<h2>Spring MVC Demo - Home Page</h2>

<hr>

<a href="showForm">Hello World form</a>
</body>

</html>
```

**Here is the Image of Directory**

[Directory Image in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6Wq2.png)

**PS:** I have tried all other option including switching the location, cleaning the directory and reinstalling tomcat and eclipse but all these are not working for me.Even, I changed the IDE from Eclipse to IntelliJ Idea but problem persists.

Comment: *For what URI*?

Comment: Here is the URL
http://localhost:8080/solution-code-spring-mvc-adding-data-to-the-spring-model/WEB-INF/view/main-menu.jsp

Comment: Can you post picture of your directory structure of project?

Comment: @JaiDixit Dear I have added the Image of Directory...Please have a look at edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your servlet name is 'dispatcher' Spring looks for the file `dispatcher-servlet.xml` in the default location of your WEB-INF folder.
Try renaming `spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml` to  `dispatcher-servlet.xml` and it will work.Hope it helps, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure your Package Names is consistent. Confirm that the package you created for the controller is same as defined in spring-servlet xml file (defined for component scanning).
AND
Clear Tomcat Cache
This is normally a caching issue with the cache.

Here are some steps to clear the Eclipse cache and Tomcat cache.

1. In the Server's tab in Eclipse, Stop the Tomcat server
2. Right-click the server and select "Clean..."
3. Right-click the server again and select "Clean Tomcat Work Directory..."
4. In the Eclipse, select the top-level menu option, Project > Clean ...
5. Be sure your project is selected and click Ok
6. Restart Eclipse

Comment: It worked for me - my lecture as a matter of fact.